# NodeJS piping from tar packing to webhdfs error

Tags: javascript, node.js, hadoop, tar, webhdfs

I am currently building a node app that uses hadoop as long term storage for data when a service of mine is not running. Because of the expected amount of transfers that will be expected to happen and the least amount of processing time is preferred, data is not written to disks but instead directly piped to what I intend to do with it.

I am receiving the following error:

```
\nodejs_host\node_modules\webhdfs\lib\webhdfs.js:588
    src.unpipe(req);
        ^

TypeError: src.unpipe is not a function
    at Request.onPipe (\nodejs_host\node_modules\webhdfs\lib\webhdfs.js:588:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pack.Stream.pipe (stream.js:103:8)
    at Object.hadoop.putServer (\nodejs_host\hadoop.js:37:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\nodejs_host\hadoop.js:39:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

I have based my code on the following documentation:

https://github.com/npm/node-tar/blob/master/examples/packer.js
https://github.com/harrisiirak/webhdfs/blob/master/README.md (writing to remote file)

This is the code I have written:

```
var webhdfs = require('webhdfs');
var fs = require('fs');
var tar = require('tar');
var fstream = require('fstream');

var hdfs = webhdfs.createClient({
    path: '/webhdfs/v1',
    // private
});

var hadoop = {}

hadoop.putServer = function(userid, svcid, serverDirectory, callback){  
    var readStream = fstream.Reader({path: serverDirectory, type: 'Directory'})
    var writeStream = hdfs.createWriteStream('/services/' + userid + '/' + svcid + '.tar')
    var packer = tar.Pack({noProprietary: true})

    packer.on('error', function(){console.error(err), callback(err, false)})
    readStream.on('error', function(){console.error(err), callback(err, false)})
    writeStream.on('error', function(){console.error(err), callback(err, false)})
    writeStream.on('finish', function(){callback(null, true)})

    readStream.pipe(packer).pipe(writeStream);
}
hadoop.putServer('1', '1', 'C:/test', function(){console.log('hadoop.putServer test done')});
```

The documentation suggests this should be working, would anyone be kind enough to tell me what I did wrong?

Had a gander at lib\webhdfs:588 [here](https://github.com/harrisiirak/webhdfs/blob/master/lib/webhdfs.js#L588)

```
req.on('pipe', function onPipe (src) {
// Pause read stream
stream = src;
stream.pause();

// This is not an elegant solution but here we go
// Basically we don't allow pipe() method to resume reading input
// and set internal _readableState.flowing to false
canResume = false;
stream.on('resume', function () {
  if (!canResume) {
    stream._readableState.flowing = false;
  }
});

// Unpipe initial request
src.unpipe(req); // <-- Line 588
req.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so me looking around over issues on the github pages of these modules and found someone mentioning abandoning the tar package for tar-fs. Gave it a shot and instantly working :)

So if someone is having a related issue with webhdfs & tar, take a look at tar-fs
https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs